# Кастомные аллокаторы памяти

Tags: c++, c, malloc

Читал статью про кастомные аллокаторы, но не могу понять, как они выделяют память именно на куче, разве есть какой-то способ взять память на куче, кроме malloc/new? Или в функцию передается большой кусок памяти?

```
typedef struct _LinearBuffer {


uint8_t *mem;       /*!< Pointer to buffer memory. */
uint32_t totalSize; /*!< Total size in bytes. */
uint32_t offset;    /*!< Offset. */
} LinearBuffer;

/* non-aligned allocation from linear buffer. */
void* linearBufferAlloc(LinearBuffer* buf, uint32_t size) {


if(!buf || !size)
return NULL;


uint32_t newOffset = buf->offset + size;
if(newOffset <= buf->totalSize) {
void* ptr = buf->mem + buf->offset;
buf->offset = newOffset;
return ptr;
}
return NULL; /* out of memory */
}
```

Comment: В буфере заранее выделяется большой кусок памяти (на куче). Потом аллокатор просто из этого буфера берёт небольшой кусок.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А это не очень накладно с точки зрения производительности?

Comment: Наоборот, это выгодней. Выделение памяти на куче - дорого. Но оно делается только один раз. А далее - просто сдвиг указателя - это быстро.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я имел в виду по количетсву памяти, получается нам нужно заранее проаллоцировать большой кусок, даже если он нам не понадобится.

Comment: Да, в начале тратим много времени. Зато потом очень быстро выделяем.

Comment: Почему они должны выделять память на куче? Собственно готовой кучи может вообще не быть. Это на Windows для процесса всегда создается как минимум одна куча.

Comment: [Пул памяти](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Пул_памяти), [Объектный пул](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Объектный_пул)

Comment: @VTT а можно поподробнее, где/в каких случаях не может быть готовой кучи? На каких-то определённых платформах?

Comment: На платформах, отличных от windows. А даже если куча имеется, то не факт, что аллокатор должен использовать именно ее.

Comment: malloc под капотом использует mmap

Comment: @magrif, например в ms-dos или когда вообще нет ОС

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть работы `LinearAllocator` следующая

> 1. Выделение куска памяти в куче

```
LinearAllocator la(64); //malloc

|________________________________| (64byte)  A
```

> 2. Получение куска памяти с под А. Построение объекта Object

```
Object * obj1  = new(static_cast<Object*>(la.allocate(sizeof(Object)))) Object;

|оbj1|___________________________|
```

> 3. И так, дальше можем заполнять кусок памяти

```
|obj1|obj2|obj3|_________________|
```

Помните, что LinearAllocator может очистить только весь кусок памяти, то есть удалить только obj3 не получится (`Stack Allocator` умеет).

Деструктор нужно вызывать явно.

```
 obj1->~Obj();
 obj2->~Obj();
 obj3->~Obj();
```

Плюсы: Внутренняя фрагментация сведена к минимуму(Пространственая локальность).

Минусы: Нет контроля объектов.